# 'libxml/tree.h' file not found when archiving the project in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, store

I am using the libxml.2.2.7.3.dylib library in my project, in order to use TouchXML. When I am running this project in simulator and on an iOS device my application runs without any warnings nor errors.

However, when I am trying to archive my project (getting ready to hit the App Store) I am getting this error:

> 'libxml/tree.h' file not found.

I know the error is with regards the settings for the included files, but I can't see where the problem lies. I would think that when I can compile it for the iOS device and simulator it should work perfectly!

Comment: What's the Xcode version and the iOS SDK you're building with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you included the header search path in your debug build but not release.  Check to make sure that the path to libxml is there in both in your build settings.

As a bit of further explanation, when you compile to the device to test, you typically do so in debug mode.  When you compile for submission or archive you always do so in release mode.  These two modes each have separate settings, and sometimes you might accidentally have a setting in one but not the other.  So when you compile for test, the search path is there and everything is fine, but in release mode it is not and you get that error.